# ESP32: how to tick external watchdog during OTA update procedure?

Tags: arduino, esp32, watchdog

I'm using ESP32 `#include <Update.h>` to update the firmware via Update.begin() Update.write() and Update.end() methods.

Which is the right way to include an external watchdog tick during the update? My external watchdog hardware is reseting during the update procedure.